# use AngularJs NgResource to load JSON file from localhost

Tags: javascript, angularjs

## Overview

I am building an app (running on MAMP) that holds contact information that will expand to hold more data such as project name & deadline, once this part is functional.

### Questions

When the user visits `/projects.php#/project/` I would like them to see a list of all the project names with a link to their detail page.

1. How should I write the following to access all of my data?

Do I need the .json at the end?

What does the @id do?

`return $resource('data/project.json/:id', {id: '@id'});`

When the user visits `/projects.php#/project/a-gran-goodn` I would like them to see the details about this project(for now, just the name & address).

2. How should I write the following to return my data by Id?
   `$scope.project = $routeParams.id ? Project.get({id: $routeParams.id}): new Project();`

### plunkr file

http://plnkr.co/edit/7YPBog

### project.json

This file lives on `http://localhost:8888/angularjs/ProjectsManager/data/project.json`

```
[
{ "address" : [ " 3156 Dusty Highway",
        " Teaneck New Jersey 07009-6370 US"
],
        "id" : "a-gran-goodn",
        "name" : "Grania Goodner",
        "phone" : " (862) 531-9163"
},
{ "address" : [ " 62 Red Fawn Moor",
        " Rodney Village West Virginia 25911-8091 US"
],
        "id" : "b-aime-defranc",
        "name" : "Aimery Defranco",
        "phone" : " (681) 324-9946"
}
]
```

### app.js

```
var projectsApp = angular.module('projects', ['ngResource']);

projectsApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
          .when('/', {
    controller: 'ProjectListCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'partials/projectlist.html'})
          .when('project/:id', {
    controller: 'ProjectDetailCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'partials/projectdetail.html'
  })
          .otherwise('/');
});

projectsApp.factory('Project', function($resource) {
  return $resource('data/project.json/:id', {id: '@id'});
});

projectsApp.controller('ProjectListCtrl', function(Project, $scope) {
  $scope.projects = Project.query();
  console.log($scope.projects);
});

projectsApp.controller('ProjectDetailCtrl', function(Project, $routeParams, $scope) {
  $scope.project = $routeParams.id
          ? Project.get({id: $routeParams.id})
          : new Project();
});
```

### partials/projectlist.html

```
<a href="#/project/" class="btn">Add new item</a>
<ul class="unstyled">
    <li ng-repeat="project in projects">
    <div class="well">    
      <h2><small>{{project.id}}</small> {{project.name}}</h2>
      <a href="#/project/{{project.id}}" class="btn btn-link">View Info for {{project.name}}</a>
        </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

### partials/projectdetails.html

```
<h3>Information</h3>
<p>Name: {{project.name}}</p>
<p>Phone Number: {{project.phone}}</p>
<p ng-repeat="line in project.address">{{line}}</p>
```

### index.php

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="projects">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title ng-bind="title" ng-cloak>Restaurant &mdash;</title>

    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ProjectListCtrl">
    <a class="brand" href="#">Projects Manager</a>

    <div id="app-container" class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span12" id="main" ng-view>
        </div><!--/.span12-->
      </div><!--/.row-fluid-->
      <footer>Copyright Projects &copy; 2013</footer>
    </div><!--/.container-->


    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Don't forget to load angularjs AND angular-resource.js --> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.js></script>
    <!--Controllers-->
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you accessing the JSON file directly, or going through some server that exposes RESTful URLs? `$resource` is designed to work with RESTful-style URLs, it's probably not the best choice for a plain, flat file.

Comment: @BrandonTilley For testing purposes, I have it as a flat json file but I will eventually convert it to a sqlite database on LAMP server. What would be the approach if I just kept it as a flat file though?

Comment: I would probably just use `$http` to fetch the entire file, and then use JavaScript code on the client-side to do any necessary "querying." Of course this may only work well until the JSON reaches a certain size.

Comment: You really should put all of this in a plunkr.

Comment: @JamesKleeh I just added that to my post.

Comment: @BrandonTilley Is it possible to provide some sample code for this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you can't query against a raw JSON file like you can with RESTful-style URLs (which is what `$resource` is built to do), you can instead get a copy of the JSON and then build your own `query`, `get`, etc. that looks at the data and returns the right thing. It's a bit tricky because you also want to support `new Project`, which doesn't really make sense when using a file-backed store, but this example supports it:

```javascript
projectsApp.factory('Project', function($http) {
  // Create an internal promise that resolves to the data inside project.json;
  // we'll use this promise in our own API to get the data we need.
  var json = $http.get('project.json').then(function(response) {
    return response.data;
  });

  // A basic JavaScript constructor to create new projects;
  // passed in data gets copied directly to the object.
  // (This is not the best design, but works for this demo.)
  var Project = function(data) {
    if (data) angular.copy(data, this);
  };

  // The query function returns an promise that resolves to
  // an array of Projects, one for each in the JSON.
  Project.query = function() {
    return json.then(function(data) {
      return data.map(function(project) {
        return new Project(project);
      });
    })
  };

  // The get function returns a promise that resolves to a
  // specific project, found by ID. We find it by looping
  // over all of them and checking to see if the IDs match.
  Project.get = function(id) {
    return json.then(function(data) {
      var result = null;
      angular.forEach(data, function(project) {
        if (project.id == id) result = new Project(project);
      });
      return result;
    })
  };

  // Finally, the factory itself returns the entire
  // Project constructor (which has `query` and `get` attached).
  return Project;
});
```

You can use the results of `query` and `get` like any other promise:

```javascript
projectsApp.controller('ProjectListCtrl', function(Project, $scope) {
  $scope.projects = Project.query();
});

projectsApp.controller('ProjectDetailCtrl', function(Project, $routeParams, $scope) {
  $scope.project = $routeParams.id
          ? Project.get($routeParams.id)
          : new Project();
});
```

Note the change to `Project.get($routeParams.id)`; also, the [updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mzQhGg?p=preview) also fixes a problem in your `$routeProvider` configuration.

This is all demonstrated here: http://plnkr.co/edit/mzQhGg?p=preview

Answer (score 2):

i will paste here a generic code i use to fetch json from your local or a remoteserver maybe it will help you:

it uses a factory that you can call when you need it.

```
app.factory('jsonFactory', function($http) {  
  var jsonFactory= {      
    fromServer: function() {        
        var url = 'http://example.com/json.json';
            var promise = $http.jsonp(url).then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
        });      
      return promise;
    },
    hospitals: function() {     
        var url = 'jsons/hospitals.js';               
            var promise = $http.get(url).then(function (response) {
          return response.data;
        });      
      return promise;
    }        
    };
  return jsonFactory;
});
```

Then when you need to call it:

```
function cardinalCtrl(jsonFactory, $scope, $filter, $routeParams) {
   jsonFactory.hospitals().then(function(d){
        $scope.hospitals=d.hospitals;
   });
   jsonFactory.fromServer().then(function(d){
        $scope.fromServer=d.hospitals;
   });

}
```